# Complex Limit Without L'hopital's

Tags: complex-analysis, limits-without-lhopital

I'm trying to solve for the limit of the following complex function as $z\to0$. I know L'hopital's rule but I'm to find the answer without using that method. The limit is:

$$\lim_{z \to 0} \dfrac{e^z+z\log (z)}{1-z^2\arg(z)} $$

I know the issue will be with the $\log (z)$ term since $\log(0)$ is not defined. Can anyone see what I should be doing here?

Comment: It isn't an indeterminate form. Take the limit of numerator and denominator each, then divide.

Answer (score 0):

$$L=\lim_{z \to 0} \dfrac{e^z+z\log (z)}{1-z^2\arg(z)} $$
$$L=\dfrac{\displaystyle\lim_{z\to0}e^z+z\log (z)}{\displaystyle\lim_{z\to0}1-z^2\arg(z)}$$
$$L=\dfrac{\displaystyle 1+\lim_{z\to0}z\log (z)}{\displaystyle\lim_{z\to0}1-z^2\arg(z)}$$
For the upper limit, perform change of variables $z\mapsto\frac1z$
$$L=\dfrac{\displaystyle 1+\lim_{z\to\infty}\frac1z\log (\frac1z)}{\displaystyle\lim_{z\to0}1-z^2\arg(z)}$$
$$L=\dfrac{\displaystyle 1-\lim_{z\to\infty}\frac{\log (z)}z}{\displaystyle\lim_{z\to0}1-z^2\arg(z)}$$
Since for any $a>0$ there exists a $Z$ such that for all $z>Z$ it is true that $z>a\log z$.
$$L=\dfrac{1}{1-\displaystyle\lim_{z\to0}z^2\arg(z)}$$
$$L=\dfrac{1}{1-\displaystyle\lim_{z\to0}z^2\cdot\lim_{z\to0}\arg(z)}$$
Since $\arg$ as a codomain of $[0,2\pi]$. Note that the notation $[a,b]$ below means that it's some unknown value guaranteed to be inclusively between $a$ and $b$
$$L=\dfrac{1}{1-0\cdot[0,2\pi]}$$
$$L=\dfrac{1}{1-[0,0]}$$
$$L=1$$